# Photon Fusion WebGL Round Trip Time is 5 times slower than the desktop version

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, photon

I have a game built using Photon Fusion, everything is working perfectly fine on the desktop version, the round trip time is around 30ms which is perfect. But with the same settings, when I connect to the server with the WebGL build, it's 5 to 7 times slower. In a competitive game, 200ms is not acceptable, so I am trying to solve this problem. Both WebGL and desktop clients are connecting to a dedicated server on a remote linux machine. I also tried to use Websockets on Fusion settings for both server and the client builds, but it did not make a big difference.

I am attaching both the webgl and the desktop version screenshots for comparison.

https://us.v-cdn.net/6024696/uploads/BBICMAOZWDSP/screen-shot-2022-10-10-at-10-55-50.png
https://us.v-cdn.net/6024696/uploads/DNTSKBXPYQ4M/screen-shot-2022-10-10-at-10-56-05.png

Note: I asked the same question on photon forum but no answers there https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/21110/webgl-round-trip-time-is-5-times-slower-than-the-desktop-version/p1?new=1